# Term for when the sound of a movie starts before the image

Tags: soundtrack, terminology, sound-effects, editing

Is there a technical term for when the first sound of a movie is heard while the screen is still black?

A hypothetical example: we hear the sound of howling wind for a second or two before we see an establishing shot of a mountain range.

Comment: Related: [Sound of a next scene starts one moment earlier than video](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/18690/49)

Comment: Not just related, but that question answers this one. It's a J Cut.